# Как передать подписку другой функции

Tags: typescript, angular

У меня есть функция userService, я оформляю на нее подписку. Если нет ошибок забираю данные и хочу вернуть их с возможностью другой функции оформить на нее подписку.
У меня уже был похожий вопрос но там было две вложенных функции, там вопрос был решен с помощью switchMap. Но как здесь его можно использовать?
чтобы можно было написать вот так:

```
this.authService.getUser(1).subscribe(...
```

Но вот такой код выдает ошибку, я и сам понимаю, что это не правильно, но не пойму как тут использовать switchMap или map:

```
export class AuthService {
getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {  
  this.httpService.getUser(id).subscribe(
    (resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
      if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
        return resultService.data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
}
}

export interface User{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Мне нужно не просто вернуть данные из предыдущего сервиса, а чтобы тут была обработка полученных данных и в зависимости от этого будут возвращены разные данные. В примере я ее сократил, что бы код уменьшить, на самом деле ее будет больше. Я только для этого и засунул эту функцию в отдельный сервис, чтобы в компоненте было минимум кода. А если просто вернуть результат, то вся логика уйдет в компонент, а в этой функции ваще смысла не будет.

Comment: `return this.httpService.getUser(id);`

Comment: Наверно мне надо было это указать в вопросе. Но мне нужно не просто вернуть, а чтобы тут была обработка полученных данных. В примере я ее сократил, что бы код уменьшить, на самом деле ее будет больше. Я только для этого и засунул эту функцию в отдельный сервис, чтобы в компоненте было минимум кода. А если просто вернуть результат, то вся логика уйдет в компонент, а в этой функции ваще смысла не будет.

Comment: ты хочешь возвращать Observable, поэтому и должен вернуть Observable. Если ты хочешь обработать значение, используй [operator map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) перед возвращением значения

Comment: вот я и не пойму как тут этот map исползовать

Comment: как и [любой другой оператор](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как функция должна возвращать `Observable` внутри нее должен находиться `return`.

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {  
  return this.httpService.getUser(id)
```

Для преобразования результата, можно воспользоваться [оператором `map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map)

```
map((resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
  if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
    return resultService.data;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
})
```

Для применения операторов используется метод [`.pipe`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe).

В итоге, код может выглядеть так:

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {  
  return this.httpService.getUser(id).pipe(
    map((resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
      if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
        return resultService.data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })      
  )
}
```